# Is there a standard way to store arbitary settings in an XML file for use by .net?

Tags: .net, xml, settings

Ideally I'd be using files of the same basic structure as an app.config and pulling settings buy so long as I can get any sort of "pathed" XML storage for settings I'd be okay.

Ideally given something like :

```
<Root>
 <ApplicationSettings>
  <Setting key="SomeKey", value="SomeValue"/>
 </ApplicationSettings>
</Root>
```

I'd call something like:

```
Settings.Get("ApplicationSettings.SomeKey");
```

and get "SomeValue" as an lresult.

Anyone know of any easy standard commonly in place way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

A long time ago, Craig Andera has described [the last configuration handler you'll ever need](http://alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Craig/XmlSerializerSectionHandler.html).  It uses app.config to provide the configuration. You could modify it to get the config from somewhere else.

**EDIT**
It appears as though the above link has been moved
http://sites.google.com/site/craigandera/craigs-stuff/clr-workings/the-last-configuration-section-handler-i-ll-ever-need

Comment: I started down this path, but found that .NET 4.0 has made this way, way easier.  Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx if you are using more modern .NET frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, as you seem to be familiar with the App.Config file... There is a method very similar to what you posted. Create an App.Config file for your project, and put the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Key1" value="Value1" />
        <add key="Key2" value="Value2" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And then you can access it in your code using:

```
string key1= ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Key1"];
```

Comment: but I don't want to use the literal App.Config seeing as allowing it to change is against best practice.

Comment: @firoso - I think I'm missing something about your question... What do you need to use the App.Config file for? The App.Config file is the standard way to save configuration settings in a .NET project, for use throughout the project.

Comment: what do you mean allowing it to change is against best practice? I'd assume you mean editing the web.config is against best pratice, but you can keep static values in web.config and reference additional values in an external app.config (see http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/04/09/5261.aspx)  The only value I see in your question as posted is the ability to add many different files and/or configuration sections.

Comment: he's saying "same basic structure as app.config", not necessarily THE app.config.

Comment: ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings works if the settings are in the app.config/web.config, an included config, the machine.config the machine's web.config, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The standard is to use app.config/web.config.

I have no idea where you heard that changing it is not best practice - I think someone is trying to fool you.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a function that pulls the Value.  I have done this

```
 Public Class Settings
     Public Function GetSetting(Byval SettingsKey As String) As String

        Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
        xDoc.Load("app.config")
        Dim xNode As XmlNode
        xNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(("Settings/setting[@item='" & SettingsKey & "']"))
        If xNode Is Nothing Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return xNode.Attributes("value").Value
        End If
        xDoc = Nothing

    End Sub
End Class
```

And then call it like this

```
Settings.GetSetting("MyArbitraryKey")
```